# Trouble with openlayers v4.6.5 uploading geoJSON

Tags: openlayers

I have been following a few books but they all seem to be about OpenLayers 3.  Things have apparently changed since then.  I am having a lot of trouble viewing a geojson over a basemap layer.  The bing basemap seems to work just fine.... I have gone into about:configure and turned the security to false on firefox.  Someone said that could be interfering with loading something from disk into the web... Is there an easier way?? Can i just upload these into some database like SQL server and have them inserted by command?? I am going crazy.  I can usually follow along with books or websites but everything is outdated.  This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>First Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css"> <!--open layers style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="features.css"> <!-- my style sheet for the 
different tools -->
<script src="ol.js"></script><!-- open layers javascript -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<div id="mymap" class="mymap"></div>
<select id="layer-select"> <!--this is the drop down menu for picking layers 
-->
<option value="AerialWithLabels">Aerial with labels</option>
<option value="Aerial">Aerial</option>
<option value="RoadOnDemand">Road</option>

</select>


<script>

var styles =[

    'RoadOnDemand',
    'Aerial',
    'AerialWithLabels',


];
var layers =[];
var i, ii;
for (i=0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i){
    layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: '---------------',
            imagerySet: styles[i]
        })
    }));
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
        })
    }),
    url: 'C:\\Users\\----------zips.geojson'
});


var map = new ol.Map({
    layers:  [vectorLayer], layers,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    target:'mymap',
    controls: [
      new ol.control.Zoom(), //default
      new ol.control.Rotate(), //default
      new ol.control.Attribution(), //default
      new ol.control.ZoomSlider(), // new
      new ol.control.MousePosition(), //new
      new ol.control.ScaleLine(), // new
      new ol.control.OverviewMap() //new
    ],
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
        new ol.interaction.Select({
            layers: [vectorLayer]
        })
    ]),

    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [-95.422956, 29.765985],
        zoom: 11

    }),



});

var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
function onChange() {
    var style = select.value;
    for (var i=0, ii = layers.length; i <ii; ++i) {
        layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
    }
}
select.addEventListener('change',onChange);
onChange();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I have also experimented with editing the vector area like this

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON,
url: 'C:\\Users\\------zips.geojson'
})

});
```

Should I just switch to leaflet.. Documentation seems up to date and I had no problem with that library when I tried doing this...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the z-index on the base layer to -1, I had the same problem and turns out I just couldn't see the GeoJSON because it was loaded first and the base layer was loaded over top of it. Once I changed my z-index's it worked fine.